# Find all items in a list with specific date using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to list the items that have a specific date and who are assigned to a particular person but for some reason, it doesn't seem to filter the list by date. The aim is to loop through each person within a group and find out what they have been tasked with by the date.

I have tried Contains and any instead but that doesn't really give me the results I'm after. The output of the 'Var i' just seems to be a list of all items across a wide range of dates.

```
foreach (String consultant in recipent)
            {
                var q = appointmentItems.Where(item => item.Name==consultant);
                ws.Cell(row, col).Value = consultant;
                col++;

                foreach (DateTime date in time)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());
                    var i = q.Where(item => item.Date == date.ToShortDateString());
                    loggedTime = 0m;
                    //dailyHours = 7.5m;
                    availableHours = 7.5m;
                    String name = "";
                    String _date = date.ToShortDateString();

                    foreach (CalenderItem item in i)
                    {
                        //populate values and workout availibile hours
                    }
                }
            }
```

Calender item class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class CalendarItem
    {
        public String Date { get; set; }

        public decimal Duration { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public bool AllDayEvent{ get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }

        public string BusyStatus { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The first linq 'Q' works fine in producing a list of items related to 1 person. The second linq 'i' does nothing and returns the same list as 'Q'.

Comment: You'll need to post more code. Where is `time` coming from for instance. Try to include a minimal working example in so far as you can make it work.

Comment: item.Date is a Date? You're comparing a date with a string. The condition will never be true, thus the list will always be empty.

Comment: `item.Date.ToShortDateString() == date.ToShortDateString()`, what happens when you try that? TBH, you should be comparing `Date` to `Date` types...

Comment: I don't know why my previous comment was deleted, but please share the definition of the Date property on the type of Item.

Comment: Sorry @JonasHøgh, item is of type calendar item and i have already converted it to type string

Comment: What is time? This is incomplete code. It seems like maybe q is supposed to be time, but you would need a select...

Comment: In what format is the date in CalendarItem.Date?

Comment: In that case, your code should work as you expect with respect to the two calls to Where. There must be something outside the provided code that trips you up. You need to work on isolating the problem into a self contained section of code.

Comment: Thanks @JonasHøgh, I did an expanded for loop and put a debug on the date. Turns out the formatting on the dates where different even though they were both strings, for example, one was 17/04/2019 and the other 17/04/2019 00:00:00

Answer (score -1):

```
 item.Date == date.ToShortDateString()
```

That doesn't look good

item.Date seems a date, date.TOShortDateString() is a string.

Different type, different format etc.

Try to do

```
 item.Date.ToShortDateString() == date.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: If item.Date were a DateTime, the code wouldn't compile, as no equality operator is defined for string and DateTime